# Android Studio Unable to locate adb within SDK in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator

I am trying to install android studio  on my ubuntu desktop  which is 32 -bit os but I am not able to  run emulator it always telling me Unable to locate adb within SDK . I have install android studio perfectly and I have also installed . This is a very strange problem .Help me to solve this problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copied from  https://askubuntu.com/questions/714653/adb-android-studio-ubuntu-error-unable-to-detect-adb-version-adb-output-hom and it works .

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Got same error after update Android Studio and then Android SDK.

[SOLUTION : Downgrade /platform-tools folder]
Download this arch. : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
Go to your Android SDK folder
Remove old /platform-tools
Insert downloaded from link above
Hope this help you.

[UPDATED]

Forgot specify that Ubuntu is 32 bit